# Query executes in MYSQL but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

There seems to be a lot of talk about this but non of the solutions fixed my problem.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM  `inductees` 
WHERE (first =  "Eric" OR last =  "Eric") 
OR (first =  "Ewing" OR last =  "Ewing")
ORDER BY  `year` DESC
```

When I paste this query into phpmyadmin's SQL box I get exactly results.  When I try to query it in php I get this:

> SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"Jack" OR last="Jack") OR (first="Ewing" OR last="Ew' at line 1

EDIT:

I've tried changing the single quotes to double quotes with no avail.

Here is the code.  I got the query string above by using the commented out return in this function

```
`if(!empty($query_vars)) {
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `inductees` WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $query_vars)." ORDER BY `year` DESC";
  //return $query;
  return $db->query($query)->execute();
} else {
  return self::all();
}`
```

Comment: Show us your PHP code.

Comment: According to the error, this obviously isn't the query being executed.  If you want help with code that isn't working, showing us *that code* would be helpful.  Also, doesn't SQL use single-quotes for strings?

Comment: show your php code..

Comment: Double quotes can potentially work, depending on the ANSI_QUOTES mode setting. It's really impossible to know what's going on here without seeing the PHP code.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're not properly escaping the double quotes within your code. Try using single quotes within the query (if wrapping the string in double quotes).

Comment: I've modified the code sample you provided as an edit. See if this works:
`if(!empty($query_vars)) {
    $where_clause = implode("','", $query_vars); //for your sake, I hope $query_vars has been sanitized from malicious user input
    $query = "SELECT * FROM inductees WHERE first IN ('" . $where_clause . "') OR last IN ('" . $where_clause . "') ORDER BY year DESC";
    return $db->query($query)->execute();
} else {
    return self::all();
}`

Comment: (Sorry, I don't know how to use line breaks in comments...)